# Isbell duality between algebras and sheaves

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, duality, adjoint-functors

nLab says on [Isbell duality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Isbell+duality#definition), the following:

> A general abstract adjunction
> $(\mathcal{O} \dashv \operatorname{Spec}) : \mathrm{CoPresheaves}  \leftrightarrows \mathrm{Presheaves}$
> relates (higher) presheaves with (higher) copresheaves on a given (higher) category $C$: this is called Isbell conjugation or Isbell duality (after John Isbell).

> To the extent that this adjunction descends to presheaves that are (higher) sheaves and copresheaves that are (higher) algebras this duality relates higher geometry with higher algebra.

I can not find a reference for this claim about sheaves/algebras.
How are algebras defined here are these algebras for some functor or a monad? Anyone knows about a paper with a proof of this adjunction descending into sheaves and algebras?

Edit: I think I might have found the correct definition for the algebras as co-presheaves here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+algebras+on+infinity-stacks#TAlgebras, but assuming this is correct still leaves open the following questions:
For the copresheaves on $T$ (presheaves on $T^{op}$), that are function algebras, sheaves on which site should these be adjoint to?
Or maybe is there a generalization that would work over any site?

Comment: One example is the case where C is a lex category, which we can view as an "essentially algebraic theory". Then the presheaf category $[C^{op},Set]$ is the classifying topos of the algebraic theory, and on the other side the adjunction between $[C^{op},Set]$ and $[C,Set]^{op}$ descends to the category $Lex(C,Set)$ of C-algebras, ie points of $[C^{op},Set]$.

Comment: The section here, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+algebras+on+infinity-stacks#TAlgebras, treating T-algebras as a full subcategory of copresheaves seems like a plausible candidate for the restriction of CoPresheaves, there they are called presheaves on C^op, still have to look into references or try working out the proof myself.